# How to convert NUMBER(9) to String with Linq to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using Oracle Client 11.2.0.3 with 11g Oracle database and having troubles to convert numberical column data to string.

```
var items = new List<string>();

items = (from x in db.Table1
         select x.ColA).ToList()); // ColA is NUMBER(9)
```

If I use `Convert.ToString(x.ColA)`, I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.String ToString(Int32) method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

If I use `x.ColA.ToString()`, I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.String ToString() method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

If I use `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.RESERVATION_ID)`, I get `The specified method System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable1[System.Double]) on the type System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items = (from x in db.Table1
         select x.ColA).ToList().Select(x => x.ToString()).toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = (from x in db.Table1 select x.ColA).ToList()
   .ConvertAll(s => s.ToString());
```